# Video transmisson using NRF24L01+?

Tags: streaming-video

Can the NRF24L01+ (+PA +LNA) be used for video transmission?

I want to build a quadcopter that would provide video surveillance; how possible is it to use the NRF24L01+ module for video transmission using raspberry pi?

Comment: Looks like it's been achieved using h265 here https://youtu.be/9N1uRcvZzq4 Currently looking into it for your same purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks implausible to me. There are some video clips at [letsmakerobots.com](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/47269) that illustrate the sort of performance you might expect, which looks like 320x240 at about 1 fps. They used it for a slow moving ground based robot - I can't imagine it would be fun to try to pilot a quadcopter at that frame rate.

The [product page](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P) suggests that the chip may be capable of up to 2Mbps. By the time you've added up overhead/packet loss/etc. you're not likely to achieve usable results.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some experimentation with the NRF24L01 for exactly this.  Using the python API & auto-ack/retransmit etc, I got about 6500 bytes/s! Absolute garbage for video.

So I tried again using a C program & all settings tweaked/disabled to squeeze every bit of perf & optimization out of it I could get.  I finally got 1.7Mb/s out of it, and I got about 300 feet away with lots of obstructions before any drastic packet loss.

Next step - how to get a decent frame rate on the 320x240 PiTFT, 16 bit color.  That's just over 2 frames a second at 1.7Mbit.  With interlacing & skipping every 2nd row, you can get about 11 FPS.  You could quantize further too if you didn't mind going a bit more retro to be a bit more responsive.

It is possible, but it's the wrong tool for the job :D it's a great low powered module for sending & receiving reliable data, but kind of unsuitable for streaming HD. I hope to write a blog about my bot one day, I really should cover how I did this.

Comment: Note that the 1.7Mb/s is one-way only.  To have input going the other way required lots of... awkward synchronization, filthy compromises & bad dreams.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look into **WiFiBroadcast** instead.

It uses COTS Wifi dongles , uses error correction 
and has many advantages if you only need to send :

https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/